The correct preposition after the noun Punishment
I heard someone from an English-speaking country, using the preposition 'of' after the noun "punishment" followed by the noun denoting 'the punisher'

So, that will be the punishment of Lord Mount.

Although he meant that Lord Mount will punish.
None of the following proves this use of 'of' right.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/punishment?q=punishment
https://www.britannica.com/topic/punishment
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/punishment
https://www.britannica.com/topic/punishment
The preposition 'of' after the noun 'punishment' makes the following noun, the receiver of the punishment.
In my example, it sounds like Lord Mount receives the punishment, right?

After the noun denoting the punisher, there has to be 'from'.


The punishment 'of a person' can mean either a punishment delivered to that person or one delivered by that person. (1) Whether called “Hansen's disease” or the “punishment of God,” leprosy was once one of the horrors of mankind and in some countries of the world it still is. (2) The Punishment of Cain. This passage looks at the result of Cain's sin and the punishment meted out to him by God.

@SeowjoohengSingapore After the noun denoting the punisher, there has to be 'from'.. I think it should be ,After the noun "punishment" (i.e. from should be used in place of "of".

Many ELL questions about "correct preposition use" fail to recognize that English prepositions are often exceptionally flexible, and / or have changed over time, irrespective of the precise contextually implied meaning. In this case, for example, quite a lot has already been written on this page, but no-one seems to have mentioned The punishment for him is [that he will spend eternity in Hell].

This question and answer from just a few days ago may be helpful.

OP has stated:

The preposition 'of' after the noun 'punishment' makes the following noun, the receiver of the punishment.

The phrase "punishment of" typically indicates the receiver of the punishment, not the imposer. For example:

"The punishment of the criminal" (the criminal receives the punishment)

However, "punishment of" can also describe the type or length of punishment:
Ref. ludwig.guru

"A punishment of 5 years in prison" (describes the punishment itself)

Interestingly, there are exceptions where "punishment of" is followed by the imposer:


The Merciful Punishment of God" (God is the imposer)
The Merciful Punishment of God.
https://www.truechristianmagazine.org/the-merciful-punishment-of-god/
"I am the punishment of God" - Genghis Khan (God is the imposer)
https://www.armyupress.army.mil/Journals/Military-Review/MR-Book-Reviews/May-2017/Book-Review-013/#:~:text=Khan%20summoned%20the%20city's%20leaders,punishment%20like%20me%20upon%20you.%E2%80%9D



In topics related to the law, crime, etc, it is very common to talk of 'the punishment of the court', so much so that I would hesitate to call such usage 'exceptional'. It is simply the case that, as so often is the case, context supplies the meaning, if common sense does not.

The punishment of my manager was that I lost three days' salary; the punishment of my manager was that he lost three days' salary. Of course, in real life, people avoid ambiguity, e.g. by using forms of words such as 'suffered by' or 'meted out by'.

This construction, where the object of of refers to the entity who has meted out the punishment, typically involves some sort of decree (by a court or tribunal, a royal personage, a deified ruler, Cap'n Ahab, etc). To use it of banal circumstances is over-the-top and even a tad confusing: Grounding me for the weekend was the punishment of my parents.

@TimR - when I was a kid 60 years ago, and more, the kids next door were great pals, being the same ages as me and my sister. Their family was devout Roman Catholic; we were (very) lax Anglican in name only really. When playing together, every time one of us tripped, barked a shin, stubbed a toe, etc, one of the girls would say 'that's God's punishment for something'.

It was no doubt a punishment for playing with heretics.

@TimR - they solemnly told me that saying 'bloody' was wicked because it meant 'by Our Lady' and that 'Cor blimey' meant 'God blind me!' and was not only wicked but foolish in case He was listening and decided to grant your wish.
